# Display unknown amount of images from database?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am newish to aspx pages but not to c#.

I have an SQL statement that will get images from ms sql database and I can do that fine and have a list or datatable of byte arrays for the images.

I think I want to use a

The part where I'm most confused is how to display a byte array as an image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an handler (*.ashx) to do the job of getting an image's bytes and writing them to the response stream. Then you reference this handler in the src="" attribute of your . Here's a tutorial on how to do this:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/

Answer (score 1):

You could use inline images if image in DB is rather small.

```
// This is just example, you get it from DB
byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\\test.png");
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image);
...
// Output in your HTML page
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= imageBase64 %>" alt="Test inline" />
```